# Отличие format от f""

Tags: python, python-3.6

```
name = "Michael"

print("Name is {}".format(name)
print(f"Name is {name}"
```

Как эти 2 варианта отличаются между собой? Какой практичнее использовать, и лучше всего?

Comment: F-Строки предоставляют способ встраивания выражений внутри строковых литералов с минимальным синтаксисом. Стоит обратить внимание на то, что f-строка является выражением, которое оценивается по мере выполнения, а не постоянным значением. В исходном коде Python f-строки является литеральной строкой с префиксом f, которая содержит выражения внутри скобок. Выражения заменяются их значением.  https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В большинстве случаев возможно применить первую или вторую форму, с тем же самым результатом.

Практически нужно взят на учет только версию Питона:

- Будет ли мой код запускаться только в Питоне 3.6+, или нет?

  - Когда нет, нужно использовать метод `.format()`.
  - Когда да, лучше всего применить f-строки, т.к. они

    - более наглядны,
    - в отличие от метода `.format()` с *ограниченным* набором допустимых выражений (в фигурных скобках) f-строки позволяют *какие-либо* выражения — см. [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#differences-between-f-string-and-str-format-expressions).

Comment: Практически, строку для `.format()` можно взять из внешнего источника (часто используется при переводе интерфейса программы на другие языки), а f-строки можно прописать только непосредственно в коде (если не читерить с eval)

Comment: Соглашусь с @andreymal, .format() позволяет делать позднюю интерполяцию, тогда как в f-строках интерполяция делается только в момент создания/ объявления. В остальном, по-моему, f-строки предпочтительнее.